# still getting android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, android

Just trying to grab a small bit of information from a php file on our MySql server to show a connection was made by the app. At this point it now crashes the app and spit out org.Apache.http.client.clientprotocolexecption, forgive me if this is a noob question, I'm only 4 months into programing in java.

**logcat:**

```
11-06 09:51:20.268: E/log.tag(2748): Error in http connection  org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    11-06 09:51:20.268: W/dalvikvm(2748): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
    11-06 09:51:20.288: E/AndroidRuntime(2748): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-83
    11-06 09:51:20.288: E/AndroidRuntime(2748): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    11-06 09:51:20.288: E/AndroidRuntime(2748):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4609)
    11-06 09:51:20.288: E/AndroidRuntime(2748):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:867)
    11-06 09:51:20.288: E/AndroidRuntime(2748):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4066)
    11-06 09:51:20.288: E/AndroidRuntime(2748):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10250)
    11-06 09:51:20.288: E/AndroidRuntime(2748):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10205)
    11-06 09:51:20.288: E/AndroidRuntime(2748):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6296)
    11-06 09:51:20.288: E/AndroidRuntime(2748):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3547)
    11-06 09:51:20.288: E/AndroidRuntime(2748):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3405)
    11-06 09:51:20.288: E/AndroidRuntime(2748):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3380)
    11-06 09:51:20.288: E/AndroidRuntime(2748):     at com.mobile.donswholesale.AppInfo$1$1.run(AppInfo.java:111)
    11-06 09:51:20.288: E/AndroidRuntime(2748):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

**Code:**

```
test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    try {

                        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://"
                                + serverIp.getText().toString()
                                + "/mobile.php");
                        httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        isr = entity.getContent();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("log.tag",
                                "Error in http connection  " + e.toString());
                        resultView.setText("Could not connect to Database");
                    }
                    try {
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(isr, "iso=8859-1"), 8);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                        isr.close();

                        result = sb.toString();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("log.tag",
                                "Error converting result  " + e.toString());
                    }

                    try {
                        String s = "";
                        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            s = s + "User :" + json.getString("UserName");
                        }
                        resultView.setText(s);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("log.tag",
                                "Error Parsing Data " + e.toString());
                    }

                    Log.d(MainActivity.DEBUGTAG, "Didn't Work ");
                    return;
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(Void results) {

                }

            }).start();
        }

    });
```

Comment: Have you add the permission : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: What is the logcat output?

Comment: I doubt you are getting the exception you think you are because the thread looks fine, however it appears you are trying to update some UI element from a non-ui thread which you cannot do

Comment: yes internet is enabled, log cat :error in HTTP connection org.Apache.http.client.clientprotocolexecption.

Comment: provide your logcat and check your permissions in the manifest

Comment: it was the networkonmainthreadexception, made a change following internet suggestion to get rid of it and now I am back at clientprotocolexecption

Comment: @Glenn post your full stack trace in your question

Comment: "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." It's right there, in the stacktrace which you probably didn't read.

Comment: `CalledFromWrongThreadException` != `NetworkOnMainThreadException` ....

Comment: Please read the stacktraces before posting!

Comment: like I said you are trying to update a UI element from a different thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use AsyncTask for the process

```
      class A extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
          protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
               String result = "";
               try {

                   HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://"
                            + serverIp.getText().toString()
                            + "/mobile.php");
                    httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    isr = entity.getContent();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log.tag",
                            "Error in http connection  " + e.toString());
                    return null;
                    //resultView.setText("Could not connect to Database");
                }
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(isr, "iso=8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    isr.close();

                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log.tag",
                            "Error converting result  " + e.toString());
                }

                try {
                    String s = "";
                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        s = s + "User :" + json.getString("UserName");
                    }
                    return s;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("log.tag",
                            "Error Parsing Data " + e.toString());
                }
          }
          protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
               if (s == null) {
                    resultView.setText("Could not connect to Database");
               }
               else {
                   resultView.setText(s);
               }

}
```

and then simply

```
test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         new A().execute();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to set text on view outside UI thread. So you've created your new thread for http access, and now you call setText from the same thread. As suggested above, use AsyncTask.